# FCM no notification on oreo when app is in foreground (below oreo it works)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I want to receive FCM notifications on my phone. I am using the code below. Now my problem is that when I am on android oreo and the app is running in foreground I dont receive the message (but on android 7 for example it works fine!). What do I have to change to get it to work? Background and when the app is killed works on both os.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    //if the message contains data payload
    //It is a map of custom keyvalues
    //we can read it easily
    if(remoteMessage.getData() != null){

        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    }

}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "TestID";

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        notificationChannel.setDescription("Description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,1000});

    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
            .setTicker("Ticker")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentInfo("info");

    notificationManager.notify(1,notificationBuilder.build());


}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Have you tried using breakpoints to see if `onMessageReceived()` is actually called for O?

Comment: No I have not. Can you send a code example how I can check it, please?